# Is using a while loop + break an acceptable way to "goto" the end of an operation?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I had a hard time constructing a query to find an answer to this-- I am interested if anybody has any input or an alternative to this scenario:

I am performing a bunch of operations in succession on a variable.   If one of these operations makes the variable meet a certain condition, I want to go ahead and skip the rest of the operations.

How I have been doing this:

```
while(true) {
  variable x;
  performOperation1(x);
  if( x meets conditions ) break;
  performOperation2(x);
  if( x meets conditions ) break;
  performOperation3(x);
  if( x meets conditions ) break;
  //...etc
}
```

I think this problem is language agnostic, but I tagged it JavaScript because that's where I'm facing the problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

Although your question is language-agnostic, I'm guessing that best answers to it are not.  For instance, here's one JS possibility:

```
var x = init(), idx = -1; 
var ops = [performOperation1, performOperation2, performOperation3, ...];
while(x doesn't meet conditions && ++idx < ops.length) {
  ops[idx](x);
}
```

It seems to meet your initial concerns quite well, but not the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452828#comment47071398_29452873) you made about not wanting to abstract these calculations into their own functions.

Another JS possibility, if you're willing to move this code into a function of it's own is the approach [described by fbelanger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452868/1243641).

I would suggest that the approach you're considering is seriously flawed, mostly because it's abusing the `while` statement.  `while` is designed as a looping mechanism.  Using it to simulate `goto` is simply missing the point of structured coding.

Comment: yeah i know about the while thing-- that's why I asked :)

i think i'm just going to pull this entire snippet out into a function, and instead of break just return

Comment: I think this answer is superior to your code because it doesn't repeat `x meets conditions` there times. Iterating over functions isn't "abstracting", and doesn't have to be hard to read. That said I don't see anything obnoxious about your initial construct either. Quite clever!

Answer (score 0):

This is not okay. Your loop should result in a false when x meets whatever condition.

```
function() {
    variable x;
    performOperation1();
    if( x meets conditions ) return x;
    performOperation2();
    if( x meets conditions ) return x;
    performOperation3();
    if( x meets conditions ) return x;
    //...etc
}
```

Comment: But that will still result in the later operations being hit?  the loop won't always just break right when I set the bool to be false (depending on language right?)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you're trying to acheive and it hit me, are you trying to simply return x? If so, replace bool = false with return x;

Comment: No, later operations won't be hit, because the `return` statements end the call to the function.

Comment: well at the end of my while loop, i take the the current value of x and display it in the UI.  but that is a good idea, abstract out the entire while loop into a function and return on it.  I like that.

@ScottSauyet, he edited the post.  Initially he changed my snippet to have `bool = false` instead of `break`

Comment: Ahh.  Well this is a straightforward approach if you don't want to abstract the operations themselves into their own functions.  If they're complex enough for that, then I would look to my implementations instead as cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using Promises you'd get a cleaner, more readable code:

```
performOperation1().then(performOperation2).then(performOperation3);
```

Your methods should return `true` or `false` in order to break the chain.

More info here: https://www.promisejs.org/patterns/

Comment: That looks cool!  I was more looking for a language-agnostic alternative though.  But yes I did tag this JavaScript so it's understandable.  The only thing is that each operation is really just some calculation applied to variable x.  So it doesn't seem reasonable to abstract every calculation out to it's own method.   I know I didn't really make that clear in the question, I'll have to edit it

Comment: I guess it really depends on the complexity of such calculations. If they're simple enough, I think your approach is sufficient.

Comment: Don't use promises for synchronous things. Unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it:

```
variable x;
[ function() { performOperation1(x); },
  function() { performOperation2(x); },
  function() { performOperation3(x); }
].some(function(f) { f(); return x meets conditions; });
```